# Is this crack between bricks a concern?

Tags: brick, mortar

I just noticed this crack that has formed along an exterior window. Does this seem like something that needs repair, or just some caulking?

I noticed that for some reason the bricks were not alternated in direction along this window like all of the other windows around my house (see second picture). This is the only issue I see with cracks in the bricks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could they have replaced an old window with a larger one and just did the brickwork on one side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the mortar joint cracked, so what I would do would is *remove a couple of those bricks,* look closely and see if there's anything suspicious behind them.

You also might want to invite any person you might know who works in the masonry field. 
And of course, if you don't know anyone, then youu might call for a free estimate regarding what's up with it. ( Having bricks removed allievates the free estimate from saying " I dunno, we're gonna have to remove a couple of bricks to see what happened behind there."

I would  believe any masonry contractor would want to look behind there as well.

If this is nothing more than a weak mortar joint, you might want to tackle this yourself with a product called Sika Bond, which is a mortar colored masonry construction adhesive 
( comes in a caulking gun tube ) which is super strong. And will bond any type masonry.

Sika Bond can be found at *both* Lowe's and Home Depot.

Good luck

Comment: thanks, that's very helpful. The thought of removing (and later trying to replace) bricks sounds like it's beyond my abilities. I may have to get a pro to look at it, or just caulk it up and see if it continues to be an issue.